# stuck with getting two minimums of several variables

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, switch-statement, minimum

I'm pretty new to PHP, still learning, but I just cant get the solution.

I have 3 variables

> $line1 = 5; 
>   $line2 = 3; 
>   $line3 = 7;

I need a hint on how to get the 2 lowest variables and IF the sum of those 2 variables is higher than the 3rd variable it should echo.

I'm guessing an if-else statement or switch, but im not sure. 
But i'm mostly stuck on how to get the 2 minimums.

Anyone can help? Sorry, im still a noob xD

Comment: Gen max variable and sum two others.

Comment: You should place those in an array instead of three different variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$all = [$line1, $line2, $line3];

sort($all);

if ($all[0] + $all[1] > $all[2]) {
    echo $all[2];
}
```

This should do.

Next time you should atleast try before asking and show us what you have done beforehand. This is not a "Cant do it, can you do it for me please?" but rather "I have done this, can you help me fix it?" type.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer if it did the job

Comment: ye, pretty new to all this, never used stackoverflow, i did try several things, but didnt post it. Something i'll keep it mind next time.

Comment: Thats why im saying those things to help you understand stackoverflow